# Google Map screen capture is not working properly using html2canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, screenshot, html2canvas

Google Map screen capture is not working properly. Grey screen appears in the output image file. For simple text in div section works fine. Any suggestion for this.

I tried like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src ="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="html2canvas.js?rev032"></script> 
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">

function initialize()
    {
    var mapProp = {
          center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
          zoom:5,
          mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
    var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

$(window).load(function(){

    $('#load').click(function(){

            html2canvas($('#googleMap'), {
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
                    window.location.href = dataURL;
                }
            });

    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
<input type="button" value="Save" id="load"/>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATED:

I replace the code section as below. Working fine but saved as .part file. Is it possible to give it a name while saving to local disk ?

```
$(window).load(function(){

    $('#load').click(function(){

            html2canvas($('#googleMap'), {
            useCORS: true,
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var dataUrl= canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");

                window.location.href = dataUrl;
                                    }
            });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a js library called [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/). Its usage is:

```
 saveAs(myImage, "image.png");
```

I'm currently trying to save the google map with html2canvas but I'm getting grey background.

Also, the new usage for html2canvas is:

```
html2canvas(cloneThisCanvas).then(function(canvas) {
    //your canvas callback
});
```